# how to convert a 32 bit integer to 2 shorts

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net, how to convert a 32 bit integer to 2 shorts? and reconstruct them?

The first 16 bit will go to the first value, the last 16 bits will go to the second value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [BitConverter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kftcaf9.aspx).

```
dim i16a, i16b as short
dim i32 as integer = somevalue
dim b() as byte

b = BitConverter.GetBytes(i32)
i16a = BitConverter.ToInt16(b, 0)
i16b = BitConverter.ToInt16(b, 2)
```

You can reconstruct the same way, just copy the 4 bytes into a single array first before using BitConverter.ToInt32.